# Is there any way in flutter to set a global textscalefactor along with the home property in Material App?

Tags: flutter, fonts, global-variables, size, text-size

I've tried to set a global `textScaleFactor` along with the `home` property in `MaterialApp` but it is not possible, because it is asking for `HomePageWidget()` separately. I am using `GetMaterialApp()` in another project and I want this global `textScaleFactor` there too, but there also I am using `initialRoute` too. Is there any way to counter this situation other than specifying this property for every single `Text()` widget?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes you can do this.
In your GetMaterialApp you can use it inside "builder" attribute of GetMaterialApp.

And still you can use title,initialRoute,initialBinding and getPages, as I have mentioned in example below.

Example:

```
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GetMaterialApp(
      builder: (BuildContext context, Widget? child) {
        final MediaQueryData data = MediaQuery.of(context);
        return MediaQuery(
          data: data.copyWith(
            textScaleFactor:
            data.textScaleFactor > 1.2 ? 1.2 : data.textScaleFactor*1.05,
          ),
          child: child!,
        );
      },
      title: kAppName,
      initialRoute: kSplashScreen,
      initialBinding: ScreensBindings(),
      getPages: RouteGenerator.getPages(),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
    );
  }
```